# Can Obstacle Limitation Surfaces Change over time?

Tags: safety, airline-operations, aircraft-limitations

I want to know whether the OLS (Obstacle Limitation Surfaces) around an aerodrome can change over time?

I know that if the ground level was altered this would change the limits of each surface.
However, my line manager told me that obstacles cannot change the OLS, and has stated that the answer is quite obvious. But I am still in training and still rather confused about it. I work in Safeguarding, so I've done some research so far, but I haven't found a decent answer from searching online.

Could I have some guidance please?

Comment: Is your manager making the distinction between an envisioned (mathematically constructed, not physical) surface, and any obstacles which penetrate that surface? Adding an obstacle wouldn't redefine that surface, although adding or lengthening a runway might, depending on how the surface is defined.